# How can you identify a known network service on an unusual port?

Tags: service, tcp, port

Given a device with an open TCP port on a non priviliged and not widely used port number from which I assume a known service like Telnet, SMTP or HTTP is running there and not on its standard port, e.g. a XMPP service on port 12345 whether this makes sense or not: How do I find out which service runs there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to scan with nmap tool.

Comment: The options -sV and -A seem to provide such functionality. Thanks for the hint, I didn't know nmap could do this.